# Armazenar valores obtidos no calculo da distancia de pontos em uma matriz

Tags: python

Estou dando os primeiros passos me `python` e  quero armazenar uma série de valores que obtive no cálculo de distância entre pontos numa matriz **N**x**N** para depois selecionar os valores de cada linha e estabelecer uma condição de valor limite, e armezenar os valores desse limite meu código ficou assim:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input('numero de elementos = '))
print('-=' *30)
v =np.zeros(n)
X = np.zeros(n)
Y = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    X[i] = float(input('x ='))
    Y[i] = float(input('y ='))
print(X,Y)
print('-=' *30)

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        dist = (((X[i]-X[j])**2)+((Y[i]-Y[j])**2))**(0.5)
        print(f'[{dist}]', end='')
    print()

R=2
for dist in range(0,n):
    if dist<=R:
        mat_distancia = dist
    print(mat_distancia)
```

Answer (score 0):

o método np.matrix() permite criar a matriz, depois podemos filtrar por condição dentro do limite definido.

```
m = []
for i in range(0,n):
    m.append([])
    for j in range(0,n):
        dist = (((X[i]-X[j])**2)+((Y[i]-Y[j])**2))**(0.5)
        m[i].append(dist)
        print(f'[{dist}]', end='')
    print()

M = np.matrix(m)
R=2
print(M[M < R])
```